# Why Ruby on Rails' User.create!(:email => 'ha', :identifier => 'foo') not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, restful-authentication

(I am using Rails 2.2.2, but should be very similar to 2.3.5 or 3.0)

The following line works:

```
User.create!(:email => 'ha')
```

But I generated a migration and added `identifier` to the users table, and restarted the Rails console, and used

```
User.create!(:email => 'bar', :identifier => 'foo')
```

This user is created with and the email field is set to `bar` (as seen in mysql) but `identifier` is not set to `foo`... is there a reason why?

---

`db/schema.rb`:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "login"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "crypted_password",                  :limit => 40
  t.string   "salt",                              :limit => 40
  t.datetime "created_at"
    [...]
  t.string   "short_bio"
  t.string   "identifier"
end
```

Comment: Is that your actual copy-pasted code? If so, you have a typo. If not, post your actual code.

Comment: oh... typo fixed... it was not due to the typo...

Comment: You're using the `create!` command correctly. If you want a better answer than that, you need to show us some code. Your model and schema at a minimum.

Comment: @Jack yes...  and the object returned by Rails console does show an `identifier` field... the db log also show an `INSERT` with `identifier` except its value is `NULL`... but the `score` has a default value of, say 20, so I wonder if there is a place that sets the default values... should it be in `models/user.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `attr_accessible` to `User` model:

```
def User
  attr_accessible :identifier
end
```

If you do not want to add `attr_accessible` for `identifier` (because say, a user should not be allowed to set their own identifier), then you need to first save the user and then set the identifier separately:

```
User.create!(:email => "a@a.com")

u = User.find_by_email("a@a.com")
u.identifier = "foo"
u.save!
```

Comment: what is the rule about this... so `create` and `create!` both need to have this `attr_accessible :field_name` if it is to able to set any initial value?  Is there docs / tutorial on this?  thanks.

Comment: `attr_accessible` means that the attribute can be "mass assigned", for example when the attributes is obtained from a form. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Comment: ah, i see... this is to protect hackers posting random records to the table if the code uses "mass assign"... so the attr_accessible is to "white list" things that can be mass assigned...